# How do I get my Emacs to *always* use 6x13 on X11

Tags: emacs, fonts, gtk, x11

I recently declared .emacs bankrupcy and reorganized my init stuff. In
the process, I ripped out all the hacky font selection stuff I had
accrued over the years, figuring there are probably easier ways to
accomplish what I want in the most modern version of emacs.

```
GNU Emacs 23.0.91.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.14.4)
on a GNU/Linux System (Ubuntu 8.10).
```

Let's
ignore, for the moment, the fact that I also run emacs under Mac OS X
(GUI+Terminal) and occasionally on Windows and just focus on the X11
case:

(Background: The font 6x13 has been part of X11 for as long as I can remember. (a.k.a
misc-fixed semi-condensed ...). It's a bitmap font.)

- I want emacs to always use the X11 bitmap font 6x13. (This gives me two buffers next to eachother on my netbook.)
- I don't want to see DejaVu Sans Mono 16pt or whatever the heck comes up by default on my netbook (it's huge!)
- I want every new frame and window to use this font.
- I want derived faces (like org-mode-column) to use 6x13 font and not mysteriously switch back to DejaVu Sans Mono
- I don't care what GNOME and X11 think the logical DPI of my screen is. I want 6x13.
- When I remote into my netbook (NX Machine) I don't want to see 6x10. I want 6x13.
- In case there's any doubt: *I want 6x13*.

What's the canonical way to do to make this happen?

And before some smart-aleck tells me about menu: Options>>Set Default
Font: the resulting dialog box doesn't even offer bitmap fonts, so
there's no way to choose 6x13. Furthermore, it doesn't solve the
problem with org-mode: table-views still come up with the wrong font.

Comment: 6x13 - the one true xterm font.  Good also because it allows three 80 column terminal windows on a 1600x1200 screen.

Comment: You guys wait a few years.  Once you get your reading glasses it won't seem near as good.

Comment: @Charlie: right you are! But, as long as I can manage 6x13, I plan to. After that, well, there's lucida console or Consolas, both are legible and scalable.

Comment: I'm quite a fan of MiscFixed, personally. ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I control this stuff from my `.Xresources` file.

Personally I have

```
emacs.reverseVideo:     true
emacs.font:             7x13bold
```

(And I quite agree... long live the bitmap fonts!  I'll take my `xterm` with

```
XTerm*foreground:       green
XTerm*background:       black
XTerm*font:             7x13bold
```

...
over the Gnome terminal any day).

If you're playing with `.Xresources` from within a session, `xrdb` command is useful to reload them.

Comment: This does exactly what I want. It even fixes the uglyness I was having with maximus and emacs interacting. (Maximus would maximize the window, while elisp code in my .emacs shrank the font -> large window, with small active area scrunched in the upper left.)

Comment: Thanks also for mentioning xrdb. That saved me much "why isn't this working" head-scratching. (It's been about 10 years since I last touched .Xresources...)

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the default frame parameters in your .emacs.

- find out the name of the font you want to use
- add the needed value to the `default-frame-alist`.

The easiest way, actually, is to use customize and customize default-frame-alist, but can also use elisp and write

```
(setq default-frame-alist 
   '(font . "-*-*-medium-r-normal--16-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-hiramin_w6"))
```

That's stolen from my emacs, you'll need to find the full font name (xfontsel?) for the font you want.

See also the [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts) on setting fonts and faces.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this with a recent Linux distribution you will have to install 6x13 first (yes, sounds obvious..). There are [instructions here](http://ptspts.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/how-to-enable-bitmap-fonts-on-ubuntu.html) for Ubuntu/Debian which should work on other distros too if you skip the apt-getting of random fonts. Install the "FixedSC" .tgz from there (it unpacks to /usr/local/share/fonts) then follow the instructions to add it to the font cache so it will appear in the Gnome Font selection dialog.