# Is there a version of Fixed 6x13 bitmap font with less whitespace (line spacing 0.8)?

Tags: macos, fonts, x11

I think the fixed 6x13 font, [FixedMedium6x13.dfont](http://yootles.com/outbox/FixedMedium6x13.dfont), the default in X11, is the best programming font.
All the others that people gush about (Consolas, Inconsolata, Proggy, Monaco) just aren't as compact (without sacrificing readability).
Or maybe I just like it.  For the purposes of this question, assume we want nothing less than the X11 fixed 6x13 experience.

In Terminal.app you can choose that font at size 13 and line spacing 0.8 and it matches the standard X11 font (the one xterms, for example, use by default) *perfectly*.

My problem is the line spacing of 0.8.
Eclipse, for example, doesn't support changing the line spacing.
(Does your favorite editor support this?  TextMate? Aquamacs?)

So I'm hoping someone somewhere has made a version of 6x13 with less whitespace so that the line spacing doesn't have to be changed.
Have you?
Perhaps that's easy to do with [FontForge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) and I may resort to trying that if necessary.
**If a 500 point bounty would motivate you to do it, say the word and you're on!**

Related questions and links:

- [Font for mac osx that is as readable and compact as the default xterm (X11) font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379682/font-for-mac-osx-that-is-as-readable-and)
- http://monkey.org/~marius/beautiful-fixed-width-fonts-for-osx.html
- http://www.ccheever.com/blog/?p=135
- [How do I get my Emacs to *always* use 6x13 on X11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623748/how-do-i-get-my-emacs-to-always-use-6x13-on-x11)
- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/revisiting-programming-fonts.html
- http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2583609

Comment: Is there a programming-related question in there somewhere?

Comment: It's a hot topic for programmers (see similar popular questions). I'll edit the question to be clear that I'm talking about programming fonts.  Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: TextMate seems to also not support customizing the line spacing.  Is there any program besides Terminal.app that supports it?

Comment: Aquamacs also does not support line-spacing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Same for MacVim.  Looks like it's only Terminal.app that supports this line-spacing trick.

Comment: Kinda lame, but you can set the TextMate line height delta in Terminal: http://secrets.blacktree.com/edit?id=25761

Comment: @pbreitenbach: Really? How? Can you make that an answer? I'd gladly mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line height can be adjusted in TextMate with a terminal trick:

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakLineHeightDelta -integer
```

Where negative integers will tighten up the line height. Default=0. You probably want something in the range of -1 to -3.

I personally like the very dense font "M+ 1m" that comes with the new Kod text editor which definitely needs the line hight adjusted. Hopefully it doesn't make me go blind.

Comment: Looks like -2 makes it precisely match the xterm font! Thanks so much for this; it's been bothering me for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Do not tempt the Font gods on this issue - Eclipse on Mac is a text-rendering abomination and should not be subject to fixed-width fonts.  Step away from the Font Preferences page.

j/k.  Have not tried but might work well for you: http://eclim.org/

Comment: Thanks David! Someone else suggested modifying Eclipse. Maybe better is to ditch it altogether.

Answer (score 2):

http://triplehelix.org/~mdl/tmp/fixed6x13.zip

This is the *only* version of fixed6x13 (in TrueType form so that it will work in any program, though obviously it will not look good when scaled to non-even multiples) that anyone has made that works without any adjustments across all operating systems.  (I made it myself after many years of anguish over the same issue, converted from Markus Kuhn's fixed6x13 ucs-fonts distribution.)

Please enjoy/share/mirror all over the place.

Comment: Awesome; thank you! These days I use SublimeText and it seems to get the line spacing right without any adjustment. Do you think your version of the font may still be better?

Comment: I believe so--I was unable to find a version that both contained the full set of glyphs and rendered correctly on Windows (particularly it was hard to get PuTTY to do the right thing) as well as OS X (in Terminal, Carbon/Aqua Emacs, etc.).

Comment: I have modified fixed6x13 to have dotted zero and curved 'l' (lowercase ell). Available for Mac, Linux and even Windows: https://github.com/soumyadipdm/Fixed6x13-dotted-zero

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with macvim. The solution was to add:

```
set linespace=-3
```

to my `.vimrc` file.